# How to embed Facebook page where people can comment on it without redirecting it to FB Site?

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I have successfully embedded our FB page on the website I am working right now. But, by default if there is someone who would add a comment on the post using the embedded page on the site it will redirect them to the FB page Link. Is there any way to embed FB page on our site without redirecting people to the FB page link once they add a comment?

Is there any hard coding needed for it to be done? Please do let me know. Thanks

I have tried using different plugin but nothing works.

Comment: You are talking about the Page plugin? No, that is not possible. If you want people to be able to leave comments on specific articles of your site, you could use the Comments plugin, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/ Those comments will be tied to the URL of your article then though, they have no direct connection to your Facebook page.

Comment: Nope. I meant our Facebook Page. I embedded our Facebook page in our site where people can also see the comments but they can't add a comment on the post within our site since it will redirect them to the Facebook page link

Answer (score -1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts/

You can add your own facebook embed page or post.

Comment: Hi Arun, I have already embedded our own facebook page but we are trying to find a solution where people can add a comment on our embedded Facebook page within our site and will not be redirected to the Facebook Page link.